# Unable to adding fortigate firewall as a Ansible host

Tags: ansible, snmp, snmp-trap, fortigate

I'm facing a problem while adding a Fortigate firewall as a 
Host machine to my Ansible Controller. Could anyone help with 
this issue? I have copied the id_rsa.pub key on Firewall but 
unable to ping that Firewall, getting an error like permission
denied.
I need to configure SNMP on Fortigate through Ansible, Once I
 fix this issue. Hope you people will help me in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help you

```
- name: Backup current config
  fortios_config:
    host: 192.168.0.254
    username: admin
    password: password
    backup: yes

- name: Backup only address objects
  fortios_config:
    host: 192.168.0.254
    username: admin
    password: password
    backup: yes
    backup_path: /tmp/forti_backup/
    filter: "firewall address"

- name: Update configuration from file
  fortios_config:
    host: 192.168.0.254
    username: admin
    password: password
    src: new_configuration.conf.j2
```

from: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fortios_config_module.html

Comment: Hi Wangjin, I tried to configure these above modules but some syntax error getting. Actually I want to configure SNMP agent on Fortigate firewalls but little confusion about few things like trap_src_ipv4, trap_hosts_ipv4 and query_hosts_ipv4. Cloud you please explain to me. Thanks for your time